# Deleting a folder on android using shell script

Tags: android, bash, shell, apk, sh

I already have this code, but I don't know how to infinite delete the folder.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
rm -r /data/data/com.tencent.ig/files/tss_tmp
touch /data/data/com.tencent.ig/files/tss_tmp
```

I'm using an [app on playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sites.mjwhitta.scripter&hl=en_US).

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite delete"?

Comment: I tried to improve the language and the link.

Answer (score 0):

well i just solve my own question

```
#!/system/bin/sh
while true
do
rm -r /data/data/com.tencent.ig/files/tss_tmp
touch /data/data/com.tencent.ig/files/tss_tmp
done
```